# Faster way to read a data file using armadilo in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

Hi I just recently discovered the armadillo library for C++ and I quite like it. I am building an application after prototyping it in MATLAB so that I can execute it much faster. The problem I am facing is that when I try to load a matrix  from a `.mat` file as follows:

```
A.load("A.mat",raw_ascii); 
//raw_ascii because I can port data to MATLAB as well.
```

it takes about 10 seconds. I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing it in armadillo or C++ in general.

Any thoughts are much appreciated, thanks.

edit 1 - the file I am trying to read is about 35MB.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: The file is about 35MB.. MATLAB is able to load it pretty fast, I am unable to do so using armadillo!

Answer (score 2):

hdf5_binary should work faster. Matlab supports this format

Comment: Unfortunately hdf5_binary only works with Mac and Linux as it says so in the documentation. :(

Comment: Well, low speed is not a surprise if you work with windows :) In this case you can write your own `load` function similar to `diskio::load_raw_ascii` at `armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp` but use only C-functions

Comment: You can still use Armadillo with hdf5 under Windows, it just takes slightly more work. Enable use of hdf5 within Armadillo (via editing include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp) and then explicitly link with the C version of the hdf5 run-time library when compiling programs.